# using TSOP4838 in anti-collision line follower

Tags: transistors, resistors, circuit-analysis, infrared, trigger

i want to use IR sensors with emitter part ( IR led ) - calibrated with an IC timer to give 38KHZ IR signal - mounted **side by side** - not face to face like the counter module - to the receiver part ( TSOP4838 ) which will turn on once something reflect the IR signal back to the receiver. [ the default is that IR signals will go straight forever without being seen by the receiver ].

I've followed the steps of a circuit using IR sensor in an object counter module it included transistors to be triggered instantly as described
[image]

the problem is that it gives an instant pulse to trigger the 7-segment display. but in here i don't need it to be instant. how could i implement it to make the LED bright as long as i block the path [ not instantly ]. and to be off whenever there's no object in front of the robot

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the circuit. It responds to a burst of 38 kHz IR, probably from a remote controller. Since any remote gives a short burst of IR when a button is pushed, the receiver produces a brief pulse as well.

In order to do what you seem to want to do, you need to learn how to drive an IR LED continuously at 38 kHz, and use this as the optical emitter whose beam gets blocked.